# Why don't database systems support 1:M and 1:1 relationships directly?

Tags: database-design, relational-database, data-modeling

I am going through Relational Databases and it was mentioned that only Physical data mode.

> 1:C (0 OR 1 ) and 1 :MC (>=1)

are supported in all relationship databases. It doesn't support both

> 1:M and 1:1

relationship directly. i am not able to understand why doesn't it support. Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: Please identify & quote your source. There are many different design approaches. A relational database or ERM design represents an n-ary relation/relationship/association by a relation/table with n attributes/columns. FKs (foreign keys) & paprticipations by entities in relationships wrongly get called "relationships" by methods/tools/presentations that don't understand the relational model or the ERM. (You can find similar confusions re "physical".)

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are asking about mandatory participation in referential integrity. In principle a RDBMS can support referential integrity constraints that are mandatory "on both sides" of the constraint, and some do allow that.

Using Tutorial D syntax:

```
CONSTRAINT non_empty_order (ORD{ordnum} = ORDITEM{ordnum});
```

This integrity constraint requires that every order must have at least one row in the ORDITEM table and one row in the ORD table. So the presence of any given ordnum is mandatory for *both* tables.

In a SQL DBMS an equivalent integrity constraint would be:

```
CREATE ASSERTION non_empty_order CHECK
(NOT EXISTS (SELECT ordnum FROM ORD EXCEPT SELECT ordnum FROM ORDITEM) AND
 NOT EXISTS (SELECT ordnum FROM ORDITEM EXCEPT SELECT ordnum FROM ORD));
```

Unfortunately most SQL DBMSs don't support ASSERTIONs. Even if they did, SQL has another limitation that gets in the way of using such constraints. Most SQL DBMSs won't generally allow you to update multiple tables simultaneously (a feature called *multiple assignment*) so when multiple tables are constrained in this way they can't usually be updated without disabling the constraint for the duration of the update.

Because of these limitations, most SQL database designers will stick with SQL's FOREIGN KEY constraint syntax for referential constraints. In SQL a FOREIGN KEY constraint does not require mandatory participation on the referencing side:

```
ALTER TABLE ORDITEM ADD CONSTRAINT fk_order FOREIGN KEY (ordnum) REFERENCES ORD (ordnum);
```

This constraint requires that every ordnum in ORDITEM must have a corresponding order but it will not prevent the creation of an empty order (meaning an ordnum in ORD but no corresponding ordnum in ORDITEM).

SQL DBMS support for integrity constraints has not improved much over the last 20 years or so. Its limitations have become second nature to many database designers who have got into the habit of leaving out business rules that don't fit into the SQL model. More complex rules tend to be implemented in applications, rules engines or database procedures, so DBMS vendors have not had much reason to improve engine-level support for referential integrity.

Comment: Some SQL systems allow constraint checking to be deferred until commit time.  That gets around some of the limitations.